# How can one implement "assert()" to make use of gcc's optimizer's static dataflow analysis?

Tags: c, gcc, assert, assertions, gcc-warning

Consider the following code....

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func( char * a, int i)
{
   printf( "%c\n", a[i]);
}

int main( int argc __attribute__((unused)), char * argv[]  __attribute__((unused)))
{
   int i = 10;
   char a[] = "abc";

   func( a, i);

   return 0;
}
```

Compile with..

```
   gcc  -W -Wall -Wextra -o b b.c
```

and no warnings.

Run it, it runs, but prints garbage.

Compile with

```
   gcc  -O3 -W -Wall -Wextra -o b b.c
```

And gcc correctly points out the error....

```
b.c: In function ‘main’:
b.c:5:21: warning: ‘*((void *)&a+10)’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    printf( "%c\n", a[i]);
                     ^
b.c:11:9: note: ‘a’ was declared here
    char a[] = "abc";
```

Hey! That's quite Smart of gcc, it analysed across the function boundary! (I have observed on large projects gcc is now astoundingly clever about this!)

Now counter intuitively, adding asserts make things worse!

Consider....

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void func( char * a, int i)
{
   assert( i < 4);
   printf( "%c\n", a[i]);
}

int main( int argc __attribute__((unused)), char * argv[]  __attribute__((unused)))
{
   int i = 10;
   char a[] = "abc";

   func( a, i);

   return 0;
}
```

Compiling without optimizations again produces no warnings, but at run time you, correctly....

```
    a: a.c:7: func: Assertion `i < 4' failed.

Compilation aborted (core dumped) at Fri May  4 10:52:26
```

But compile with ...

```
gcc  -O3 -W -Wall -Wextra -o a a.c
```

...now results in NO warnings!

ie. Although gcc *knows* the assert  *will* trigger at run time... it can't tell me at compile time anymore.

ie. Counter intuitively, adding asserts and error checks to my code has made me less safe.

I can't help feel there must be some cunning Cthulhu inspired way of utilizing what gcc clearly knows, to fail the assertion at compile time!

Any suggestions?

Update: Here is a slightly different variant....

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

static char _rangeCheckVariable;
void bunc( int i)
{

   if( __builtin_constant_p( (4))) {
      char __rangeCheck[(4)]="abc";
      _rangeCheckVariable = __rangeCheck[(i)];
   } else {
      assert( (i) < (4));
   }

   printf( "%d\n",i);
}

void func( int i)
{
   bunc( i);
}

int main( int argc __attribute__((unused)), char * argv[]  __attribute__((unused)))
{
   int i = 10;

   func( i);

   return 0;
}
```

Compiling with

```
gcc  -g3 -ggdb3 -O3 -W -Wall -Wextra -c d.c ;objdump -S d.o
```

Results in

```
d.c: In function ‘main’:
d.c:11:41: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
       _rangeCheckVariable = __rangeCheck[(i)];
                                         ^
```

ie. You sort off, almost, could construct a check_range( i, size) macro that checked at compile time that i was less than size.

Update 2: Even weirder.... The following compiles without warnings, but.....

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

static char __rangeCheckVariable;

#define asshurt(exp)                                               \
   do {                                                            \
      char __rangeCheck[2]="a";                                    \
      __rangeCheckVariable =                                       \
         __rangeCheck[(exp) ? 0 : 10];                             \
   } while(0)

void bunc( int i)
{

   asshurt( i< 4);
   assert( i<4);
   printf( "%d\n",i);
}

void func( int i)
{
   bunc( i);
}

int main( int argc __attribute__((unused)), char * argv[]  __attribute__((unused)))
{
   int i = 10;

   func( i);

   return 0;
}
```

Removed the line `assert( i< 4);` and you get

```
gcc  -g3 -ggdb3 -O3 -W -Wall -Wextra -c d.c ;objdump -S d.o
d.c: In function ‘main’:
d.c:11:22: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
          __rangeCheck[(exp) ? 0 : 10];                             \
                      ^
d.c:17:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘asshurt’
    asshurt( i< 4);
    ^
```

**Update 3:** Even weirder.

Have a play with this over at that most wonderful site [Godbolt....](https://godbolt.org/g/S6hMMh) Try flicking between -Os and -O2 optimization settings.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void assertFailure( void) __attribute__((warning("Compile time assertion failure")));

int z(void);


int main()
{
   int j;

   for(  j=0;j<4;j++) {
      if( z()) break;
   }

   if( __builtin_constant_p(!(j < 4)))
   {
      if(!(j < 4))
         assertFailure();
   }
   else
      if( !(j < 4))
         abort();

   return 0;
}
```

On -Os there are no warnings (correctly) on -O2 and above... it incorrectly assembles in a call to assertFailure.

**Update 4:** Variant that works for all optimization settings (but not for C++)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void assertFailure( void) __attribute__((warning("Compile time assertion failure")));

static unsigned u;

int z(void) { return u++ % 2u;}

#define assert(exp)                                                 \
   __builtin_choose_expr( __builtin_constant_p(!(exp)),             \
                          ((!(exp)) ? assertFailure() : (void)0),   \
                          ((__builtin_expect( !(exp), 0)) ? abort() : (void)0))

void bunc( char * a, unsigned j)
{
   printf( "%c\n", a[j]);
   // assert( j < 4);
}

void func( char * a)
{
   bunc( a, 5);
}

int main()
{
   int j;
   char a[]="abc";

   func( a);

   for(  j=0;j<4;j++) { 
      if( z()) break;
   } 

   assert( j < 4);

   assert( 4 < 5);

//   assert( 5 < 4);


   return 0;
}
```

You can play with it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/TfTyU3)  An interesting difference is gcc-5.1 warnings seem better than 8.1!

Comment: If the code gets past the `assert`, only a negative `i` would cause a problem for `a[i]`. There is no way to create a static assert from that code. But, the optimized code might eliminate the call to `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will work in your example:

```
void assert_warn_abort (void)
  __attribute__ ((warning ("assertion failure"), noreturn));

#define assert(expr)                     \
  ({                                     \
    if (expr)                            \
      (void)0;                           \
    else                                 \
      {                                  \
        if (__builtin_constant_p (expr)) \
          assert_warn_abort ();          \
        else                             \
          abort ();                      \
      }                                  \
  })
```

However, warning on every statically known assertion failure can cause many spurious warnings with heavy inlining.

Comment: To elaborate the warning, the compiler may be smart enough to figure out that the assert will always fail if it is reached, but at the same time not able to tell that it isn't ever actually reached.

Comment: Yes, I tried several variants very much like that, which produced a flood of wailures on every place programmers had used "assert(false)" to mean "this code should be unreachable". After I had replace all occurrences of that with a more intent revealing macro, alas, it still didn't help me to capture the knowledge that gcc's optimizer has.

Comment: Hmm, your __attribute__((warning("")) trick is probably better than the old char a[(exp)?-1:0] compile time assert trick. UBSan gets unhappy with vla's of size 0.

Comment: In the `else` branch of `if(expr)`, the compiler is very likely to consider `expr` as the constant `0`. I doubt this really works.